# Run Magento locally with error 500

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am having a online website and I want to edit my site locally with the use of XAMPP. Here are the things I have done below:

```
-  Change Xampp port Listen 80 to 8080
-  Install database to MySQL    
-  put my website files into htdocs    
-  change username, dbname in local.xml 
-  change web/secure/base_url and web/unsecured/base_url to http://127.0.0.1:8080/(my folder name) in MySQL database, core_config_data table
```

However, my website does not show after I have done all these.

> It occurs Error 500.

[image]

what should I do for this to display my website?

After I change the permission and files to 777, I check for the error log in the xampp files (xampp\apache\logs. The error log shows below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

If you're facing a 500 error then firstly you should search for the webserver error log, and if it's running on apache server it can mostly be found in one of these 2 locations:

Centos or Archlinux: `/var/log/httpd/`

Debian or Ubuntu: `/var/log/apache2/`

In xampp, you can find the error logs in `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`, where xampp is your installation folder, if you didn't change the `error_log` setting in PHP.

**Solution 2:**

You can simply enable all errors by setting  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` from the `index.php` file of your Magento project, something like this:

index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

.htaccess:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

You can also check errors in `/var/log/system.log` and `/var/log/exception.log`. in your Magento project's directory.

> By default Magento errors output is off. If your PHP is not
>   configured to log errors then web server will return Internal 500 error in
>   case of fatal error.

**OR** maybe you're facing this issue because of the permission to your project folders, so the first thing you should look for error in the logs and then you can easily fix it.

But, if the issue occurs due to the permission then:

```
# Change folders permission to 777
app/etc
var
media

# Change files permission to 644
index.php (main index file in magento root folder)
downloader/index.php
```

Comment: for the last part, you mention I can look for the permission, which file is it in?

Comment: Change permission to 2 files and 3 folders which are mentioned in my answer. Files: ‘index.php’ and ‘downloader/index.php’ and folders: ‘app/etc’ ‘var’ and ‘media’

Comment: After I change the permission and files to 777, I check for the error log in the xampp, the error I have uploaded picture above, is it still possible to make changes to it?

Comment: 1. Open `httpd.conf` in `C:\xampp\apache\conf` {change the path with yours) then check line 93 and removed the **#** before the line `LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so` (using notepad)
2. Restart the apache.

Comment: For now it is another issue, but you did help me in solving this problem. Really thank you for the help